# How can I print a float with thousands separators?

Tags: python, format, decimal

How can I format a decimal number so that `32757121.33` will display as `32.757.121,33`?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary In Germany, the original posters format is normal.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use [`locale.format()`](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html#locale.format):

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'German')
'German_Germany.1252'
>>> print(locale.format('%.2f', 32757121.33, True))
32.757.121,33
```

You can restrict the locale changes to the display of numeric values (when using `locale.format()`, `locale.str()` etc.) and leave other locale settings unaffected:

```
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'English')
'English_United States.1252'
>>> print(locale.format('%.2f', 32757121.33, True))
32,757,121.33
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'German')
'German_Germany.1252'
>>> print(locale.format('%.2f', 32757121.33, True))
32.757.121,33
```

Comment: With the extra pain that these calls depend on the locales available for the O.S. - furthermore, locale names wll vary across different O.S. and even different Linux distributions (meaning you have to test this on your production server, or have code which provides fallbacks until it find an existing locale)

Comment: @jsbueno: Good point. The docs also point out that `setlocale()` is not threadsafe and has several other problems, especially when used in larger, multi-module programs, so it's important to read the docs. In a small program, this arguably won't matter that much. Also, there are other locale names like `en_EN` or `de_DE` that might be more universal than `German` etc.; I haven't found a list of allowed locale settings yet, though.

Comment: so i have such a problem, that : "Caught Error while rendering: unsupported locale setti" i have tried different variants (German, german, de_DE and others). can i do it without locale ? with inly format?

Comment: What platform are you running the program on?

Comment: The problem is that it's not thread-safe and assumes that the developer wants the same effect everywhere in the program (unless it's okay to switch constantly back and forth, which is hacky and disgusting). There should be a way to get a value formatted in a given locale without having to set the entire runtime platform to that locale. Like, locale.format(format_string, value, locale) - alas, these seems to be none.

Answer (score 22):

I have found another solution:

```
'{:,.2f}'.format(num).replace(".","%").replace(",",".").replace("%",",")
```

Comment: Horrible solution. What if this gets called on thousands of strings with arbitrary lengths?

Comment: This works without all that nonsense after `...(num)`

Comment: Beautiful solution, let the compilers do their job :)

Comment: Yeh, it's bad and I'm smiling now looking at that. But it worked back in 2012 :D

Answer (score 9):

If you can't or don't want to use `locale` for some reason, you can also do it with a regular expression:

```
import re
def sep(s, thou=",", dec="."):
    integer, decimal = s.split(".")
    integer = re.sub(r"\B(?=(?:\d{3})+$)", thou, integer)
    return integer + dec + decimal
```

`sep()` takes the string representation of a standard Python float and returns it with custom thousands and decimal separators.

```
>>> s = "%.2f" % 32757121.33
>>> sep(s)
'32,757,121.33'
>>> sep(s, thou=".", dec=",")
'32.757.121,33'
```

**Explanation:**

```
\B      # Assert that we're not at the start of the number
(?=     # Match at a position where it's possible to match...
 (?:    #  the following regex:
  \d{3} #   3 digits
 )+     #  repeated at least once
 $      #  until the end of the string
)       # (thereby ensuring a number of digits divisible by 3
```

Comment: thanks a lot! if you are interested in, i have also found this variant '{:20,.2f}'.format(num).replace(".","%").replace(",",".").replace("%",",")

Comment: Why create Explanation section when you could just use [verbose](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE).

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import locale

>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_GB.UTF-8')
'en_GB.UTF-8'
>>> print(locale.format_string('%.2f', 12742126.15, True))
12,742,126.15
```

This sample code works for GB in a docker container.

```
FROM python:3.8.2-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales && \
    sed -i -e 's/# en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && \
    dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninteractive locales

ENV LANG en_GB.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL en_GB.UTF-8
```

Locales could be found by running the following command on your terminal (Linux Dirstro)

```
locale -a
```

Then a full list of locales appear:

```
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
...
en_GB.utf8
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked `def sep...`, but it doesn't change the problem of finding the local format for numbers automatically.  That is really what you want if you don't want to add lots of code to your reporting.

You could use
`g.periodsOrCommas={'thou':'.','dec':','}` where g is a globally available area.

change sep to:

```py
def sep(s:str):
    thou=g.periodsOrCommas['thou']
    dec= g.periodsOrCommas['dec']
```

Then as part of the program setup, or an inquiry to the user, set periods and commas to the required formats.  In all reports or windows, call sep to deal with floating point representation.
Lastly, you could have options in sep to specify the number of decimal places, or even the type of formatting needed. But that is way off the current question.
Thanks for a great solution to an actual problem I was facing.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33536664)