# How to print an integer with a thousands separator in Matlab?

Tags: regex, matlab

I would like to turn a number into a string using a comma as a thousands separator.  Something like:

```
x = 120501231.21;
str = sprintf('%0.0f', x);
```

but with the effect

```
str = '120,501,231.21'
```

If the built-in `fprintf`/`sprintf` can't do it, I imagine cool solution could be made using regular expressions, perhaps by calling Java (which I assume has some locale-based formatter), or with a basic string-insertion operation.  However, I'm not an expert in either Matlab regexp's or calling Java from Matlab.

*Related question:* [How can I print a float with thousands separators in **Python**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13082620/how-can-i-print-a-float-with-thousands-separators)?

Is there any established way to do this in **Matlab**?

Comment: That works but is a bit cumbersome.  I'm sure there are other ways that would be interesting/useful.

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi: Nice find - but what a complicated approach if there are simple regular expressions instead :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One way to format numbers with thousands separators is to call the Java locale-aware formatter.  The "[formatting numbers](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/formatting-numbers/)" article at the "Undocumented Matlab" blog explains how to do this:

```
>> nf = java.text.DecimalFormat;
>> str = char(nf.format(1234567.890123))

str =

1,234,567.89
```

where the `char(…)` converts the Java string to a Matlab string.

voilà!

Comment: +1: Very nice. Maybe it's worth noting that this won't work in Octave, though.

Comment: What about on a multi-language system? I want to use the EN format. Is there any way I can choose that?

Answer (score 8):

Here's the solution using regular expressions:

```
%# 1. create your formated string 
x = 12345678;
str = sprintf('%.4f',x)

str =
12345678.0000

%# 2. use regexprep to add commas
%#    flip the string to start counting from the back
%#    and make use of the fact that Matlab regexp don't overlap
%#    The three parts of the regex are
%#    (\d+\.)? - looks for any number of digits followed by a dot
%#               before starting the match (or nothing at all)
%#    (\d{3})  - a packet of three digits that we want to match
%#    (?=\S+)   - requires that theres at least one non-whitespace character
%#               after the match to avoid results like ",123.00"

str = fliplr(regexprep(fliplr(str), '(\d+\.)?(\d{3})(?=\S+)', '$1$2,'))

str =
12,345,678.0000
```

Comment: Nope, still won't work for `120501231.890123`. I took the liberty of fixing that for you.

Comment: @EitanT: btw: I fixed the parenthesis typo, and added some explanation of the regular expression. Nice teamwork :)